# Code for malloc and free

Tags: c, linux, malloc, free

Where can I find the code for malloc my gcc compiler is using at the moment? I actually want to write my own malloc function which will be a little different from the original one. I know I can use hooks et all, but I want to see the real code.

Comment: write malloc() , then got to definition. (F12 usually)

Comment: I'm working in Linux and not using any debugger. I want to know the file where it is found.

Comment: Unless you're just doing this as a learning experience, it's a very very bad idea. Poking with redefining standard functions, especially something that's as core as malloc, results in fragile, non-portable code.

Comment: Writing your own malloc doesn't mean you want to *redefine* it

Comment: Actually what I want to achieve is that a process is a replica of another process and performs the same computations as the original process. Now the replica process wants to have memory allocated at same addresses as the original one, so I need to emulate malloc for the replica process and the original has to log some information to be used by the replica

Answer (score 26, accepted):

The POSIX interface of malloc is [defined here](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/malloc.html).

If you want to find out how the C library in GNU/Linux (glibc) implements `malloc`, go and get the source code from http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/ or browse [the git repository](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git) and look at [the `malloc/malloc.c` file](https://sourceware.org/git/?p=glibc.git;a=blob;f=malloc/malloc.c).

There is also the base documentation of the [Memory Allocator by Doug Lea](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) that describes the theory of a **m**(emory)**alloc**(ator) (read this carrefully, and then decide if you really need to implement your own malloc).

Comment: Note that the implementation links are for *specific* implementations. They are not universal.

Answer (score 7):

Look in the appropriate release of glibc at the [old release site](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/)<sup>1</sup> or [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/pub/gnu/glibc/).  For example, if you are using glib 2.9, it is in [this archive](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/glibc/glibc-2.9.tar.gz).  Look for the file `malloc/malloc.c`.

You will see that it is not a trivial piece of library code.

---

<sup>1</sup> It looks like they changed the directory structure after glibc-2.9.

Answer (score 2):

`malloc()` should be in glibc.

> **Further Reading**
>   [Multithreading](http://google-perftools.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/doc/tcmalloc.html)
>   [C++ allocation
>   tricks [Video]](http://video.google.com/videoplay?docid=8718136231005757634)