# making your own malloc function in C

Tags: c, malloc

I need your help in this. I have an average knowledge of C and here is the problem. I am about to use some benchmarks to test some computer architecture stuff (branch misses, cache misses) on a new processor. The thing about it is that benchmarks are in C but I must not include any library calls. For example, I cannot use malloc because I am getting the error

```
"undefined reference to malloc"
```

even if I have included the library. So I have to write my own malloc. I do not want it to be super efficient - just do the basics. As I am thinking it I must have an address in memory and everytime a malloc happens, I return a pointer to that address and increment the counter by that size. Malloc happens twice in my program so I do not even need large memory.

Can you help me on that? I have designed a Verilog and do not have so much experience in C.

I have seen previous answers but all seem too complicated for me. Besides, I do not have access to K-R book.

Cheers!

EDIT: maybe this can help you more:
I am not using gcc but the sde-gcc compiler. Does it make any difference? Maybe that's why I am getting an undefined reference to malloc?

EDIT2:
I am testing a MIPS architecture:

I have included:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

and the errors are:

```
undefined reference to malloc
relocation truncated to fit: R_MIPS_26 against malloc
```

and the compiler command id:

```
test.o: test.c cap.h
sde-gcc -c -o test.s test.c -EB -march=mips64 -mabi=64 -G -O -ggdb -O2 -S
    sde-as -o test.o test.s EB -march=mips64 -mabi=64 -G -O -ggdb
    as_objects:=test.o init.o
```

EDIT 3:
ok, I used implementation above and it runs without any problems. The problem is that when doing embedded programming, you just have to define everything you are using so I defined my own malloc. sde-gcc didn't recognize the malloc function.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Code for malloc and free](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485586/code-for-malloc-and-free)

Comment: If you really want to implement your own malloc, have a look at the syscalls `sbrk()` and `brk()` that will help you modify the size of the heap.

Comment: a "simple" malloc is hard enough to implement.

Comment: Let_Me_Be is not duplicate. The accepted answer there uses the code from GNU library which need other imports, but I cannot do any of them. I want to know if I can write it without any syscalls.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to fix the undefined reference than to write your own malloc without system calls?

Comment: what do you mean fix the undefined reference? the bencmark calls malloc, which is not defined. What do you suggest?

Comment: @Mike: can you see my edit?

Comment: Yes, the `@` lets people know you commented. I get notified of it when you say @Mike. You're using sde-gcc, so are you working on a [MIPS architecture](http://www.mips.com/media/files/MD00428-2B-SDE6X-SUM-01.17.pdf) then? What error do you get when you `#include <stdlib.h>`?

Comment: @Mike: Yes it is a MIPS architecture. I am getting these 2 errors:
undefined reference to malloc
relocation truncated to fit:R_MIPS_26 against malloc

Comment: OK, please edit your question to show what header files you included and what your compile command was.

Comment: @ghostrider Why are you splitting it into two commands? I'm pretty sure, that if you do, you will need to manually link the proper libraries in the second command.

Comment: @Mike: You keep asking about compilation, but the undefined reference to malloc appears to be a link error. This is a common in embedded programming. Add to that that the asker is benchmarking low-level computer architecture features and not writing a user-level application, and it seems likely they are working in an embedded environment where malloc may be unavailable, as they stated. So your questions about compiling may be off the mark. If you want to pursue this, you should establish first whether malloc is actually available in the libraries (not the header files).

Comment: @ghostrider Also, you linker command is missing, how do you compile it together?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Where does the compiler documentation state that? The documentation states that malloc is fully supported.

Comment: that was the makefile as was given to me. It was tested with another test.c file that made no use of such calls and was working. Let me include the whole makefile.

Comment: @ghostrider That's still not the relevant part. You are showing compilation commands, but we need to see the linker command.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: C 2011, clause 4, paragraph 6: “A conforming freestanding implementation shall accept any strictly conforming program in which the use of the features specified in the library clause (clause 7) is confined to the contents of the standard headers <float.h>, <iso646.h>, <limits.h>, <stdalign.h>, <stdarg.h>, <stdbool.h>, <stddef.h>, <stdint.h>, and <stdnoreturn.h>.” Observe that <stdlib.h>, which declares `malloc`, is not listed.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Would you be so kind and actualy read the question you are commenting? Here is the documentation: http://www.mips.com/media/files/MD00428-2B-SDE6X-SUM-01.17.pdf Page 47

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Would you please show me the sentence where the asker states they are using the full programming environment and are **not** writing for an embedded environment with limited availability of routines (even if they are supported by the compiler)? All I am saying is that the question (and comments by the asker) contains several clues that the target platform may be limited, and that this ought to be ascertained.

Comment: If I were you I would run a mile from this work, if your having these problems I can't imagine what a mess your get into later....

Comment: @EricPostpischil OP has clearly stated that he is writing for a MIPS environment, with a compiler that claims full support of malloc. If there would be an environment issue, the compilation either would fail on `sbrk()` linking or wouldn't fail at all and the program would fail at runtime. So please, stop spamming this nonsense.

Comment: @Let_Me_Be: Objecting to clarifying the requirements is antithetical to engineering. There is no reason not to ensure the problem is defined properly. OP has stated: “ I must not include any library calls” and “I want to know if I can write it without any syscalls.” They have clearly stated their desire. If you want to answer a different question, then you ought to at least confirm the situation.

Comment: @Ghostrider seems unable to tell us when he gets the message is it when compiling, linking, running? The answer will be different for each...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is a very simple approach, which may get you past your 2 mallocs:

```
static unsigned char our_memory[1024 * 1024]; //reserve 1 MB for malloc
static size_t next_index = 0;

void *malloc(size_t sz)
{
    void *mem;

    if(sizeof our_memory - next_index < sz)
        return NULL;

    mem = &our_memory[next_index];
    next_index += sz;
    return mem;
}

void free(void *mem)
{
   //we cheat, and don't free anything.
}
```

If required, you might need to align the memory piece you hand back, so e.g. you always
give back memory addresses that's on an address that's a  multiple of 4, 8, 16 or whatever you require.

Comment: -1 Because this won't work due to allignment issues. Malloc has to consider allignment requirements, that's why standard malloc allways returns memory alligned to the strictest allignment requirement. Neither your memory buffer, nor the implementation does that.

Comment: I think you mean `if (sizeof our_memory - next_index < sz)`. (If the amount of memory we have left to allocate is _less_ than what we've been asked for then return `NULL`.)

Comment: @Let_Me_Be `This is a very simple approach...`

Comment: If he just needs two blocks of memory this is over kill.... just declare the memory blocks statically.

Comment: it is not homework, c'mon. Ok maybe I will try this but that means I will change the code of the benchmark. Can you see my edit, too?

Comment: @ghostrider According to the documentation of your compiler, malloc should work just fine. You probable have some installation/configuration issue. Also the platform is alignment sensitive, so this code definitelly won't work.

Comment: Luckily it's just code, which means it's easy to change - as I noted , the OP will need to add his alignment requirements to the code.

Answer (score 6):

Trying a thread safe nos answer given above, I am referring his code with some changes as below:

```
static unsigned char our_memory[1024 * 1024]; //reserve 1 MB for malloc
static size_t next_index = 0;

static pthread_mutex_t lock = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;

void *malloc(size_t sz)
{
    void *mem;
    pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
    if(sizeof our_memory - next_index < sz){
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
        return NULL;
    }

    mem = &our_memory[next_index];
    next_index += sz;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
    return mem;
}

void free(void *mem)
{
   //we cheat, and don't free anything.
}
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to link against libc.a or the equivilent for your system. If you don't use the standard C lib you won't get any of the startup code that runs before the main function either. Your program will never run....

You could either allocate a block of static data and use that in the place of malloc, like:

```
// char* fred = malloc(10000);
// equals

static char [100000] fred;
```

or call the standard malloc for a large block of continuous memory on startup and write yr own malloc type function to divide that down. In the 2nd case you would start benchmarking after the calling the system's malloc as to not effect the benchmarks.

Comment: Because your original answer was completely irrelevant to the question.

Comment: My original answer to "I cannot used malloc because I am getting the error 'undefined reference to malloc' " was to link against lib.c, not sure that was irrelevant or that you will get anywhere with out doing so....

Answer (score 2):

I am sharing the complete approach for Malloc and free it works on every scenario. This is complimented using array. We can also implement using link list for metadata.

There are three Scenarios We have to Cover

1. Continuous Memory allocation: Allocate memory in continuous manner
2. Allocated memory between two allocated memory: When Memory is free to allocate in between two allocated memory block. we have to use that memory chunk for allocation.
3. Allocated from Initial block When Initial block is free.

for detailed You can see in diagram. [Diagram for allocating algo of memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q8BX4.jpg)

Source code for malloc

```
#define TRUE        1
#define FALSE       0

#define MAX_ALOCATION_ALLOWED       20
static unsigned char our_memory[1024 * 1024];

static int g_allocted_number = 0;
static int g_heap_base_address = 0;

typedef struct malloc_info
{
    int address;
    int size;
}malloc_info_t;

malloc_info_t   metadata_info[MAX_ALOCATION_ALLOWED] ={0};

void* my_malloc(int size)
{
    int j =0;
    int index = 0 ;
    int initial_gap =0;
    int gap =0;
    int flag = FALSE;
    int initial_flag = FALSE;
    void *address = NULL;
    int heap_index = 0;
    malloc_info_t temp_info = {0};

    if(g_allocted_number >= MAX_ALOCATION_ALLOWED)
    {
        return NULL;
    }

    for(index = 0; index < g_allocted_number; index++)
    {
        if(metadata_info[index+1].address != 0 )
        {
            initial_gap = metadata_info[0].address - g_heap_base_address; /*Checked Initial Block (Case 3)*/
            if(initial_gap >= size)
            {
                initial_flag = TRUE;
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                gap = metadata_info[index+1].address - (metadata_info[index].address + metadata_info[index].size);  /*Check Gap Between two allocated memory (Case 2)*/
                if(gap >= size)
                {
                    flag = TRUE;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    if(flag == TRUE)    /*Get Index for allocating memory for case 2*/
    {
        heap_index = ((metadata_info[index].address + metadata_info[index].size) - g_heap_base_address);
    
        for(j = MAX_ALOCATION_ALLOWED -1; j > index+1; j--)
        {
            memcpy(&metadata_info[j], &metadata_info[j-1], sizeof(malloc_info_t));
        }
    }
    else if (initial_flag == TRUE) /*Get Index for allocating memory for case 3*/
    {
        heap_index = 0;
        for(j = MAX_ALOCATION_ALLOWED -1; j > index+1; j--)
        {
            memcpy(&metadata_info[j], &metadata_info[j-1], sizeof(malloc_info_t));
        }
    }
    else /*Get Index for allocating memory for case 1*/
    {
        if(g_allocted_number != 0)
        {
            heap_index = ((metadata_info[index -1].address + metadata_info[index-1].size) - g_heap_base_address);
        }
        else    /* 0 th Location of Metadata for First time allocation*/
            heap_index = 0;
    }

    address = &our_memory[heap_index];
    metadata_info[index].address = g_heap_base_address + heap_index;
    metadata_info[index].size = size;

    g_allocted_number += 1;
    return address;
}
```

Now Code for Free

```
void my_free(int address)
{
    int i =0;
    int copy_meta_data = FALSE;
    
    for(i = 0; i < g_allocted_number; i++)
    {
        if(address == metadata_info[i].address)
        {
            // memset(&our_memory[metadata_info[i].address], 0, metadata_info[i].size);
            g_allocted_number -= 1;
            copy_meta_data = TRUE;
            printf("g_allocted_number in free = %d %d\n", g_allocted_number, address);
            break;
        }
    }
    
    if(copy_meta_data == TRUE)
    {
        if(i == MAX_ALOCATION_ALLOWED -1)
        {
            metadata_info[i].address = 0;
            metadata_info[i].size = 0;
        }
        else
            memcpy(&metadata_info[i], &metadata_info[i+1], sizeof(malloc_info_t));
    }
}
```

For testing Now Test code is

```
int main()
{
    int *ptr =NULL;
    int *ptr1 =NULL;
    int *ptr2 =NULL;
    int *ptr3 =NULL;
    int *ptr4 =NULL;
    int *ptr5 =NULL;
    int *ptr6 =NULL;
    
    g_heap_base_address = &our_memory[0];

    ptr = my_malloc(20);
    ptr1 = my_malloc(20);
    ptr2 = my_malloc(20);
    
    my_free(ptr);
    ptr3 = my_malloc(10);
    ptr4 = my_malloc(20);
    ptr5 = my_malloc(20);
    ptr6 = my_malloc(10);
    
    printf("Addresses are: %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d, %d\n", ptr, ptr1, ptr2, ptr3, ptr4, ptr5, ptr6);

    return 0;
}
```