# Version of malloc used on Linux

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, malloc

I'm just looking at the comments at the top of the `malloc.c` file in glibc and it says this:

> You may already by default be using a C library containing a malloc
>   that is  based on some version of this malloc (for example in
>   linux). You might still want to use the one in this file in order to
>   customize settings or to avoid overheads associated with library
>   versions.

I dont understand why glibc code would be saying a version of Linux may be using something different to the code in glibc `malloc.c`? Could somebody please help re-word what it means? I thought that glibc `malloc()` is what every linux would be using for memory management?

Comment: At the moment that comment was written, it was not yet part of glibc, right? When it was added to glibc, the comment was not stripped out (and there are good reasons for that).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It says so because the malloc implementation in glibc is based on [ptmalloc](http://www.malloc.de/en/), which again is based on the [Doug Lea malloc](http://gee.cs.oswego.edu/dl/html/malloc.html) implementation from which those comments orignate from. That malloc implementation was imported and made the default in glibc version 2.3.

As ptmalloc/Doug Lea's malloc implementation was a separate library you could use to replace the standard malloc() on your system, those comments applied. But the comments have been kept when introducing that library into glibc.

Comment: So basically that part of the comment should have been removed as its out of context?

Comment: @user997112 There are good reasons not to alter the source just because it has been included into glibc.

Comment: @JimBalter Just above that comment in the glibc sources there's also a comment staing that substantial changes were made to adapt it to glibc and "Do not look for much commonality
  with the ptmalloc2 version." There probably arn't that many good reasons.

Comment: Thanks guys. Im just looking at memory allocation- am I right in thinking I only really need to concentrate on malloc.c, arena.c and memmem.c?

Answer (score 0):

You could link a different library providing `malloc` (e.g. some `libmalloc` or [libtcmalloc](http://goog-perftools.sourceforge.net/doc/tcmalloc.html) ...) See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6485586/841108).

You could link a different libc, e.g. [MUSL libc](http://musl-libc.org/) providing its own malloc. So you can have a Linux application not using the `malloc` from GNU libc...

And the GNU libc can be used on other systems (Hurd, Solaris, AIX...) having their own system `malloc` ....

Some applications might provide their own `malloc` or some wrapper. (Think of [libgc](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Hans_Boehm/gc/) ...).

You could play `LD_PRELOAD` tricks to overload `malloc`, see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6083624/841108).

And your application can have been statically linked (e.g. to an older version of `libc` or to MUSL libc...). You might even have several `libc` .... (several versions of GNU libc).

Comment: This doesn't answer the question ... compare to the answer by nos.