# Why does the free() function know about the size of a malloced variable?

Tags: c, memory, malloc, free

How does free() function work? We pass an only pointer on the first element of the array or string for free and this function "know" about the right border of allocated memory and freed it correctly.
But why can't get this information from any C- standard functions?

Comment: This is implementation dependent. A common implementation is to have a block header preceding the data. That is, the header can be found by subtracting a fixed amount from the pointer returned by malloc.

Comment: Please note that while such prefix blocks are common, if you attempt to access it from your application you're really going out of bounds of the memory area allocated by `malloc` and you will have *undefined behavior*.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6485586/code-for-malloc-and-free Check this answer, it contains links to malloc source code and description of it's work. When you know how the memory is allocated, you know how it can be deallocated.

Comment: And can you please elaborate on your question and your problem? Why do you need to get "this information"? Do you have an underlying problem that you think could be solved by that? Always please ask about your actual and underlying problems directly, it makes it easier to help you with them instead.

Answer (score 1):

Usually the allocated dynamically block of memory contains a prefix where the size of the allocated memory is stored.

So the function free can access this prefix to know the size of the deallocated block of memory.

Comment: Is there a possible way to get access to this prefix from C?

Comment: If realloc() can, you could, too. But: why would you want to?

Comment: @AntonGolovenko Not in a standard-defined way.

Comment: @IanAbbott Could you share how?)

Comment: @AntonGolovenko You should investigate the implementation of the function free in your system.

Comment: @AntonGolovenko don't try to do this, it's totally implementation dependent and not standard. And you don't need this. However if you manage to do this for your particular implementation it might work...until you upgrade to the next version where it might not work anymore. Don't do this. Don't waste your time on this.